# Extra spacing with \onslide in table in Beamer

Tags: beamer, tabularx

I want to use `\onslide` to gradually uncover the contents of a table in Beamer. But this creates extra spacing beween the lines.

Consider this code, which contains two tables on one slide:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
 
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X}
        Alpha & Beta \\
        Gamma & Delta
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{column}
 
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X}
        \onslide<2->{Alpha} & \onslide<3->{Beta} \\
        \onslide<4->{Gamma} & \onslide<5->{Delta}
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{column}
 
  \end{columns}
 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This generates the following layout:

[image: Example]

As you can see, the left table has a different line spacing than the right table.

How do I make the right table similar to the left one?

**EDIT**

I noticed that if I use format `l` instead of format `X`, in `tabularx`, the problem disappears. But I need to use `X`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the problem by using a `tblr` (from the tabularray package) instead of your `tabularx`

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
 
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{tblr}{X X}
        Alpha & Beta \\
        \strut Gamma & Delta
      \end{tblr}
    \end{column}
 
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{tblr}{X X}
        \visible<2->{Alpha} & \visible<3->{Beta} \\
        \visible<4->{Gamma} & \visible<5->{Delta}
      \end{tblr}
    \end{column}
 
  \end{columns}
 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

... by using the cool trick from https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2000#a2242 you could even uncover the cells automatically:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
 
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{tblr}{X X}
        Alpha & Beta \\
        \strut Gamma & Delta
      \end{tblr}
    \end{column}
 
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={X X},
        cells={cmd=\visible<+->}
      }
        Alpha & Beta \\
        Gamma & Delta
      \end{tblr}
    \end{column}
 
  \end{columns}
 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]